# Как можно достать элементы из списка?

Tags: python

Открываю на чтение тхт файл:

```
with open('id_task_id_user.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as read_file:
        data_txt = read_file.read()
```

Получаю тип текста str

```
>>>(['823ffa61-60ae-4301-a1ad-ebea025e9986'], ['b68899cf-7672-4ee7-ba7e-6383a30c7f43', '0f1f7943-4574-4436-9412-bc9112e3ec80', '4f41a062-f117-457f-9706-30261d19a8d0', '65dd117c-7764-40ca-aee0-a6f3feb91f05', '7eac705c-a56d-4b1a-9e0f-de788f7b58fd'])
```

Далее меняю формат на лист, чтобы проиндексировать элементы:

```
data_list = [data_txt]
```

Получаю:

```
>>>["(['823ffa61-60ae-4301-a1ad-ebea025e9986'], ['b68899cf-7672-4ee7-ba7e-6383a30c7f43', '0f1f7943-4574-4436-9412-bc9112e3ec80', '4f41a062-f117-457f-9706-30261d19a8d0', '65dd117c-7764-40ca-aee0-a6f3feb91f05', '7eac705c-a56d-4b1a-9e0f-de788f7b58fd'])"]
```

И мне нужен обратится к двум спискам внутри списка (надеюсь правильно написал), чтобы был отдельно

```
['823ffa61-60ae-4301-a1ad-ebea025e9986']
```

и

```
['b68899cf-7672-4ee7-ba7e-6383a30c7f43', '0f1f7943-4574-4436-9412-bc9112e3ec80', '4f41a062-f117-457f-9706-30261d19a8d0', '65dd117c-7764-40ca-aee0-a6f3feb91f05', '7eac705c-a56d-4b1a-9e0f-de788f7b58fd']
```

, хотел обратится к ним через data_list[0] и data_list[1], но выводы печальные на принте.
Через сплит тоже пробовал, но выходит так себе (либо я плохо разделял)

Comment: а покажите кусок исходного файла. возможно, что-то можно преобразовать сразу при чтении

Comment: `data_list = [data_txt]` никак не меняет "формат", вы просто оборачиваете исходную строку в список. Чтобы распарсить строку такого вида, как вы показали, нужно использовать `ast.literal_eval`. Примеры см. в дублирующих вопросах.

Comment: Часть кода, которая идет до
```
id_call_task = calling_task(token)
         id_call_task_split = id_call_task.split()
         id_user = add_user(token, id_call_task)
         ids = ([id_call_task], id_user)
f = open('id_task_id_user.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8")
         f.write(str(ids))
         f.close()

```

Comment: @insolor абсолютно прав. Помогла следующая конструкция:
text_to_list = ast.literal_eval(data_txt)
Спасибо огромное!